# Using a filter in php that includes Variable injection - issue (wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress, code-injection

I need to add a class to a link that WordPress generates and have found the following filter:

```
add_filter('previous_post_link', 'post_link_attributes');
add_filter('next_post_link', 'post_link_attributes');

function post_link_attributes($output) {
    $injection = 'class="btn btn-default btnprev"';
    return str_replace('<a href=', '<a '.$injection.' href=', $output);
}
```

Will the $injection part cause issues with my service provider, as I've read that 'injection' is associated with Malware injection, is bad practice and could result in suspension of service - apologies for paranoia!

Many thanks

Comment: No, I certainly hope not. You are not actually injecting anything, just concatenating in a variable. If your provider is scanning code for names like "injection" to ban, you should find a new host immediately :) (note: your provider is almost certainly _not_ doing that).

Comment: Besides - if hosts triggered bans on words like _injection_, malware authors would just name their variables `$happy_rainbows` instead :)

Comment: Thanks Michael - thanks for that (somewhat embarrassingly!)

Comment: Don't be embarrassed, it's an honest question. My comment was meant as humor, not derision.